# How to calculate R squared from coefficient estimates table?

Tags: r-squared, model-comparison, regression-coefficients

I'm super confused how to find which model has a higher r-squared value when this is all the information I've been given, I feel like it should be fairly simple but I can't find how to do it any where. There are two models and they have given me these tables to try work it out from.[image]

Comment: Is this probably a homework question? If so, please include a `self-study` tag and read its [Wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).